# how to forward all traffic over a GRE over IPsec VPN on cisco routers?

Tags: vpn, cisco, gre

i have 2 cisco ISR 2821 and 2811 and they are connected over a site to site GRE over IPsec vpn.
my question is that, how can i forward all traffic or web traffic to the other router?

thanks

Comment: Dear Malan 
thanks for the quick answer. 
i added the default route and it is working.
all of the traffic is routing to the second router but now i need to nat the traffic to get access to internet.
how should i config the NAT on the second router so that the first router can access internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOU can set the default route to inside the tunnel. And make sure route that need to extablish the vpn tunnel manually statically routed to the gateway.